# Purpose of Date type in Input element

Tags: html

In HTML5 What is the purpose of input element type date,

How it is useful,

if i use the date type in my input element,

if i access site in mobile, then automatically my mobile default date picker will call or not,

Answer (score 3):

> What is the purpose of input element type date

It accepts dates.

> How it is useful,

It allows the browser to validate that a date has been entered and to provide a date picker widget.

> if i access site in mobile, then automatically my mobile default date picker will call or not,

That depends on the browser supporting the date input, not on the portability of the device the browser is running on.